# Accessing values in array of hashes where the values are arrays of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I'm in an array & hash rabbit hole, please excuse verbose question.

I'm trying to display values in a view. I created my hash by combining hashes together and grouping them by a value, so my data looks like this:

```
[
  {"447478xxxxxx"=>[
                     {:cbrs=>[
                               {"telephone_number"=>"447478xxxxxx", "type"=>"cbr"}
                             ]
                     }, 
                     {:pupil_calls=>"0"}, 
                     {:returned_calls=>"0"}
                    ]
  }, 
  {"447440xxxxxx"=>[
                    {:cbrs=>[
                              {"telephone_number"=>"447440xxxxxx", "type"=>"cbr"}
                            ]
                    }, 
                    {:pupil_calls=>"0"}, 
                    {:returned_calls=>[
                                       {"from_number"=>"447952xxxxxx", "to_number"=>"447440xxxxxx", "type"=>"call", "duration"=>50, "direction"=>"outbound"}, 
                                       {"from_number"=>"447952xxxxxx", "to_number"=>"447440xxxxxx", "type"=>"call", "duration"=>nil, "direction"=>"outbound"}
                                       ]
                    }
                   ] 
  },
  {"447588xxxxxx"=>[
                      {:cbrs=>"0"}, 
                      {:pupil_calls=>[
                                       {"from_number"=>"447588xxxxxx", "to_number"=>"441483xxxxxx", "type"=>"call", "duration"=>5, "direction"=>"inbound"}
                                      ]
                      }, 
                      {:returned_calls=>"0"}
                    ]
  }
]
```

In my view I am trying to do this sort of thing

```
<% array.each do |a| %>

<%= a.first_key %> #this is the number at the start each group eg 447478xxxxxx`

<% a.cbrs.each do |c| %>

   <%=c.type%> #for example, this is just limited sample of the scope of the data

<%end%>

<% a.pupil_calls.each do |c| %>

   <%=c.from_number%> - <%=c.to_number%> 

<%end%>

<% a.returned_calls.each do |c| %>

   <%=c.duration%>

<%end%>

<%end%>
```

But I don't know how to go about accessing the values contained within the hashes within the arrays within the hashes within the array! (Think I got that right.)

Edit: What I'm after is simple enough - I just want to be able to do something like this for each item in array:

```
 Tel: 447478xxxxxx 
 CBRS: 1 
 Calls: 0
 Returned: 0

 Tel: 447440xxxxxx
 CBRS: 1
 Calls: 0
 Returned Calls: 2 
 Call first returned about 5 minutes after CBR #This would be using created_at dates for example, there is a lot of info I didn't include in my sample data.   
 Returned Call 1: recording link
 Returned Call 2: recording link
```

Hope that helps, I just wrote out the output without html etc. The above would be as a result of looping through array of hashes and for each hash looping through it ...

Comment: can you give us the desired output?  You've shared your code but failed to tell us where it failed vs. what you're after.

Comment: Essentially my question contains the desired output with my pseudo code above, for example I'd like to be able to loop through the 'cbrs' for each item in the array of hashes : as I show with 

`<% array.each do |a| %>

<%= a.first_key %> 
<% a.cbrs.each do |c|
   <%=c.type%>
<%end%>` 

Ie the output would be `447478xxxxxx
cbr`

Comment: I just edited my question to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be refactored another 4 or 5 times but this should get you what you're after:

```
def val_check(num)
  if num.is_a? Array
    num.size
  else
    num
  end
end


phone_numbers.each do |number|
  number.each do |key, value|
    puts "Tel: #{key}"
    puts "CBRS: #{val_check(value.first[:cbrs])}"
    puts "Calls: #{val_check(value[1][:pupil_calls])}"
    puts "Returned Calls: #{val_check(value[2][:returned_calls])}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Tel: 447478xxxxxx
CBRS: 1
Calls: 0
Returned Calls: 0
Tel: 447440xxxxxx
CBRS: 1
Calls: 0
Returned Calls: 2
Tel: 447588xxxxxx
CBRS: 0
Calls: 1
Returned Calls: 0
```

Comment: Hey @Anthony, what if the order of the values can not be guaranteed? Say value.first[:cbrs] -  what if that is not the first value? How would you write the line `puts "CBRS: #{val_check(value.first[:cbrs])}"` if you do not know which order the `[:cbrs]` appears in?

Comment: I can `cbrs = value.find {|x| x[:cbrs] }` then `cbrs.values[0].first["name"]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your first error being thrown? Looks like you need to access things like c["from_number"] and c["to_number"].

Comment: Well, you are using a mix of symbols and strings.

Comment: The first thing I'm accessing is the number, in my pseudo code in the question I use <%=a.first_key%> it is actually <%=a.keys.first%>. The first error I am getting at the minute is undefined method `cbrs' for #<Hash:0x007fe2956010b0> as you can't perform a loop as I suggest in my pseudo code.

Comment: Once inside the loop, using `a.values` will give you the values of the hash you are in..which would then allow you to check `[:cbrs]` and the like for the "0"(no items) or actual array items display.